# PHP return anything in LAMP DigitalOcean

Tags: php, digital-ocean

I have problem, why this happen , its returning some php code in echo with json_encode

```
?>?> { $error = true; $message = "Betting is close, you can't bet right now"; } $json = array('error' => $error, 'message' => $message); echo json_encode($json); $conn->close(); } RegxReplace('includes/chat.php', '500','400'); function writeFile() { file_put_contents("includes/chat.php",""); } ?>
```

i got this error in url status.php?status
what i'm wrong , when i use in my xampp localhost its working fine. take a look of my full code

This is my full code

https://pastebin.com/CHrqKTxU

Comment: You haven't actually told us what precisely goes wrong?

Comment: Hmm i dont know why this happen, because when i use localhost its working no output like that, but when it on a LAMP stack with apache2 and php7.2, i got following output, is any i misconfigure in php? i just follow the tutorial in installing lamp in digital ocean

Comment: It's still not very clear. You mean it shows your PHP code on screen, instead of executing that code?

Comment: yep, when i visit the url status.php?status , i got some code display, but not all code show